# Dependency errors when installing Cinelerra from a PPA

Tags: ppa, cinelerra

I am trying to install cinelerra,

I have followed the instructions in https://launchpad.net/~cinelerra-ppa/+archive/ppa

basically

open the terminal and

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinelerra
```

but after the last line, in the terminal appears this...

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    cinelerra : Depends: libguicast1 (= 1:2.2-0.3~ppa1~oneiric1) but 1:2.2-0.6~ppa1~oneiric1 is to be installed
>                Depends: libmpeg3cine (= 1:2.2-0.3~ppa1~oneiric1) but 1:2.2-0.6~ppa1~oneiric1 is to be installed
>                Depends: libquicktimecine (= 1:2.2-0.3~ppa1~oneiric1) but 1:2.2-0.6~ppa1~oneiric1 is to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I am using ubuntu 11.10 32bits

Answer (score 1):

You have broken packages, try running `apt-get` with `-f` to fix broken packages:

```
sudo apt-get -f
```

Then update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install again.